# Who is handling flags?

Tags: support, beta, flagging

Who handles flags during the private beta? I know the site's moderators typically handles them, but we don't (to my knowledge) have any yet.

Comment: Are there even any flags? Everyone has VTC permission.

Comment: I've flagged a few comments for things like "no longer needed" or "should be moved to chat since extended discussions in comments are discouraged on StackExchange".

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59692/who-is-notifed-when-a-post-is-flagged-in-a-private-beta

Comment: @Bbrk24 Comment flags get handled by mods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's essentially one of the duties of the Stack Exchange Community Management team to watch over private beta sites. This is until the site gets it's own moderation team.

> They **moderate brand new sites** as they launch, answer questions and attempt to communicate lessons learned on past sites. They run the process to obtain the initial set of Pro Tem mods, and hand the site off to them.

You can learn more about the Stack Exchange Community Management Team here:

[Who is on the Community Management Team, and what does it do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/)

Comment: Just cleared a bunch of flags - not all of them but many.